# Storing tibbles inside of tibbles

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to create a tibble column that stores other arbitrary tibbles.

I have managed to do this with the following code, by first using `nest()` on each inner tibble then using `unnest()` on the outer tibble

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

df_outer <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  1,  2,
  4,  6,
  5,  7
)

df_nested <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b,
  1,  2,
  4,  6
)

df_outer[["data"]][1] <- nest(df_nested)               # Insert first tibble
df_outer[["data"]][2] <- nest(as_tibble(2*df_nested))  # Insert arbitrary other tibbles
df_outer[["data"]][3] <- nest(as_tibble(3*df_nested))

df_outer <- df_outer %>% unnest()
```

While this approach works, I feel like this is the wrong way to do it, since I need to call `unnest()` on the result. Is there a cleaner to way to accomplish this? Note that I want to insert the inner tibbles one at a time.

Comment: Sorry, that should say `df_outer`.

Comment: Can you check the solution i posted below.  In your solutioin, you may have to `unnest` twice as it is a nested list, but in my solution, only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to create a new column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_outer %>%
      mutate(data =  map(row_number(), ~ .x * df_nested))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This does create the same data.frame as above. However, in the code that I'm trying to write, I don't have every tibble available at once because I'm receiving them from a database. Would the only clean solution be to put them in a list to accumulate them then use `mutate` to insert them into the outer tibble? Or is it possible to insert them directly into the outer tibble one at a time?

Comment: @MattSteadman If that is the case as soon as you receive the data, update a `list` in a `for` loop or so.  I am not clear about how the whole infra in your case